# angularjs, dynamic directive form validation

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

For example, I have a select, and an input (idcard) in the form. The select determines the id-card-type (Tax id, Car license id) of input, I want to add a directive into the input to custom validate its value, and the validation method is different by its type(id-card-type) (determined by the select).

I am thinking to dynamic change the directive to validate, or one directive do validation for all types, but how to pass the type information into the directive.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it without a *directive*:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  
  $scope.type = 'tax';
  
  $scope.yourForm = {};
  $scope.yourForm.inputType = {};
  $scope.yourForm.inputType.$valid = false;

  $scope.validate = function(type, text) {
    // return boolean based on your validation for the input string and type (tax or car)
    $scope.yourForm.inputType.$valid = (type === 'tax');
  }  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form name="yourForm">
      <select ng-model="type" ng-change="validate(type, text)">
      <option>tax</option>
      <option>car</option>
    </select>
  
    <input type="text" name="inputType" ng-model="text">
    input valid: {{yourForm.inputType.$valid}}
  </form>
</div>
```

In my example, validation of the input is false when `'car'` is selected.

Of course, you can wrap all this into a *directive*.

Comment: sorry, i did not describe it clear, i have updated my question. I do not need to change input dom.